# I don't have any idea how I can do rhinoplasty surgeon

Tags: animation, boolean-modifier, makehuman

I already did a human model, but right now I don't know how I can render cuts in the nose like in this video. I will be really glad for any advice

Anatomy of the nose:

[image: nose anatomy]

Rhinoplasty surgeon animation (cuts, removing & moving parts, creating & closing gaps, fading in and out of parts):

[image: Rhinoplasty surgeon animation]

Full animation example:
https://www.instagram.com/reel/Csg0cG-oJlg/?igsh=azY5bGs0aHlyYjMz

Comment: Hello, your question is too broad for Blender Stack Exchange, what point are you precisely struggling with?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. If you could [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck we can vote to reopen it.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and where you are stuck now? In a nutshell: With Makehuman or another free tool you can create a human head. Then you need to model the inner parts of the nose (e.g. sculpting + retopology). With the shader of the skin you can make parts of skin invisible/transparent (*Alpha* input of the *Principled BSDF*). For the cuts use a thin block object that is not rendered with the *Boolean* modifier to make cuts. I guess at some point you need to fake things. E.g. use to 2 part objects, the original & one with cuts & gaps to control their visibility for the animation.

Comment: The deformations can be done with Shape Keys or an armature (or maybe modifiers).